# Сервер не видит изображения. Pythonanywhere

Tags: python, apache, python-3.x, wsgi

Я уже задавал вопрос, но теперь проблема видится иначе.
Есть проект на Bottle на хостинге Pythonanywhere. 
Так в проекте указан роут к папке с файлами

```
@route('/static/<filename>')
def server_static(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='static')
```

Файлы хранятся в `/home/username/static/`.
CSS + JS сервер видит и они работают.
Изображения не видит, выдает ошибку 404
В справке написано: `The URL /static/ should map to the folder /home/myusername/myproject/assets`, окей, сделал копию всех файлов в указанном месте, но результата нет.
А вот wsgi.py

```
# This file contains the WSGI configuration required to serve up your
# web application at http://<your-username>.pythonanywhere.com/
# It works by setting the variable 'application' to a WSGI handler of some
# description.
#
# The below has been auto-generated for your Bottle project
import bottle
import os
import sys

# add your project directory to the sys.path
project_home = u'/home/username/mysite'
if project_home not in sys.path:
    sys.path = [project_home] + sys.path

# make sure the default templates directory is known to Bottle
templates_dir = os.path.join(project_home, 'views/')
if templates_dir not in bottle.TEMPLATE_PATH:
    bottle.TEMPLATE_PATH.insert(0, templates_dir)

# import bottle application
from bottle_app import application
```

Все шаблоны, скипты, стили работают, а изображения - нет.
Я положил комплект изображений уже во все папки, но их словно нигде нет.
Я уже не знаю, что еще можно сделать?..
Где ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

Саппорт Pythonanywhere ответил просто... 
Все дело в регистрозависимости.
Ваш файл имеет расширение `.JPG`, поэтому вы должны запрашивать `.JPG`, а не `.jpg`
Теперь до меня дошло еще и то, почему я вижу эти картинки, во время работы с тестовым сервером на домашнем компе с Виндой, но не вижу их на хостинге и когда тестировал на смартфоне. Регистрозависимость!

Comment: скорее всего, регистрозависимость у самого хостинга?

Comment: Да. Они используют Линукс (вроде бы даже Убунту).

Comment: Странно, мое приложение с сайтом лежит на малинки(raspberry pi). Но может это особенности самого bottle

Answer (score 0):

```
def show_pic():
picture_name = 'my_picture.png'
return template('template', picture=picture_name)
```

В шаблоне:

```
<img src="path/to/picture/{{picture}}">
```

И не забудьте указать серверу, откуда ему получать изображения:

```
@route('/path/to/picture/<picture>')
def serve_pictures(picture):
   return static_file(picture, root='path/to/picture')
```

Взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28649595/bottle-python-how-to-display-a-picture-inside-a-template)

Comment: Не совсем подходит, так как путь к изображению формируется ЯваСкриптом. То есть выбираем из выпадающего списка пункт и скрипт закидывает `<img ... src="path/to/images/1.jpg>` в разметку. Если использовать вышеуказанный способ, то скрипт закидывает `{{picture}}` вместо `1.jpg`

Comment: @Skotinin значит вам нужно передавать скриптом, саму картинку в питон, а потом уже дальше через него указывать, что эта за картинка (3й код)

Comment: Питон к тому врмемени уже сформировал страницу и ждет следующего запроса. Посмотрите эту страницу http://skotinin.pythonanywhere.com/new Нажмите кнопку "Добавить позицию" и выберите наименование.

Comment: @Skotinin для этого существуют GET и POST запросы, чтобы постоянно менять то или иное на веб странице.

Comment: Не хочется все усложнять. Добавление/изменение будет нуждаться в перезагрузке страницы, в то время, как скрипт может менять какие-то вещи самостоятельно. Но теперь начинаю понимать, что после загрузки страницы, путь к серверу закрыт для скрипта. Однако, на встроенном тестовом сервере это прокатывает.

Comment: @Skotinin перезагрузка не нужна, просто во время выбора наименования, вы будете выполнять GET запрос на картинку и её подставлять.

Comment: Пожалуй займусь перепиской питоноскрипта. Но все же хочется разобраться, почему, я могу набрать в браузере `site.com/static/script.js` и я увижу текст скрипта, но `site.com/static/image.jpg` ведет к ошибке 404. Физически они лежат в одной папке, права у всех 755, в маршруте не указан тип файлов.

Comment: @Skotinin не знаю, похож ли Bottle с Flask, но у меня в моем HTML коде, путь к картинкам прописан так - `src="static/images/<image>`. Сами картинки лежат в `site.com/static/images`

Comment: Проверьте, пожалуйста, можно ли открыть картинку, набрав в адресной строке браузера `site.com/static/images/image.jpg`? И можно ли открыть яваскрипт/стиль таким же образом?

Comment: @Skotinin у меня открывается и то и другое. `<img width="60" height="60"  src="static/images/Raspi-PGB001.png">` Картинка лежит в `<project_folder>/static/images/Raspi-PGB001.png`

Comment: @Skotinin попробуйте в своем коде везде где написано `src="/static/.... `убрать `/` перед `static`

Comment: Не вышло. Я уже пытался методом перебора вводить в адресную строку все возможные пути, но открывается все кроме картинок. Чудеса какие-то...

Comment: @Skotinin Вы читали - http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#routing-static-files http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28532523/bottle-display-image-using-file

Comment: Да, конечно. Без этого грузится только голый HTML. Ни стилей, ни яваскриптов не будет. Я написал в поддержку хостинга.

Comment: @Skotinin хорошо. Я помог чем смог...

Comment: Большое спасибо. Снова все перечитываю, в ожидании ответа от ТП :)